# Manage data in a realtime simulation

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue, real-time

I am working on a real-time simulation project for a vehicle and looking for advice regarding the best solution in C# to handle the data generated at each timestep.

Basically, I've got the main engine that computes a solution in real-time and can live on his own. In parallel, I need to store the data generated somehow - but without any real time requirements. At each timestep, I am generating sqlite command lines and looking for a solution to execute it in parallel without slowing down the main engine.

Is there any advice around to put together the best structure to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "best", but a very good solution would be to put the data into a queue and have a separate thread that reads data from the queue and persists it.

The primary advantage is that the thread collecting the data doesn't get bogged down waiting for the database. It can just enqueue data for that timestep and go back to what it's doing (presumably getting data for the next timestep).

The thread that's persisting the data can run independently. If the database is fast enough, if can do a database insert for every time step. Or it might batch the data and send multiple records at once to do a batch insert.

To make all this happen, create a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (shared queue) that the collecting thread writes to and the persisting thread reads from. `BlockingCollection` handles multiple producers and multiple consumers without any need for you to do explicit locking or anything like that. It's real easy to use and it performs quite well. It makes this kind of thing very quick to implement.